# Python Selenium find element with following sibling by class, id, a (hreff or class)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selector

I need help with finding an exact element and click it with following-sibling based on specific id number and then classes and a (href or class).
Here is simplified code, the below example occurs many times just with different id:

```
<div class="class_1" id="1234567">
   <div class="class_2">
      <div class="class_3">
         <div class="class_3.1">
         <div class="class_3.2">
         <div class="class_3.3">
            <div class="class_3.3.1">
               <div class="class_3.3.1.1">
               <div class="class_3.3.1.2">
               <div class="class_3.3.1.3">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="event-media-icon live-icon icon-white" data-sport="soccer"></a>
...
```

How can I locate an element with id and class for example something like this and click on it:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'class=class_1 and id="2222222" and class="event-media-icon live-icon icon-white').click()
```

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#2222222 a.event-media-icon.live-icon.icon-white').click()`

Comment: Thanks, I already tried it earlier but always gives me this error: ```selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

Comment: Double-check your selector then. You may have inadvertently used spaces instead of dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xpath` you are looking for will look like the following:
`//div[@class='class_1' and(@id='1234567')]//a[@data-sport='soccer']`
I guess the elements between the upper `div` and the goal `a` are not important so we can omit them.
The `href` value looks not unique too so I preferred using `data-sport` attribute that can be more unique.
To give more precise answer I need to see that web page with dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

This xpath should work fine too

```
.//div[@class='class_1' and @id='1234567']//following-sibling::a[@data-sport='soccer']
```